# Handle Unauthorized Request and Return Status Code 404

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I am developing a standalone .Net Core API targeting framework .Net Core 2.2.
The authentication scheme is JWTBearerTokens connecting to our ADFS Identify server.
When I call an API endpoing decorated with the [Authorize] attribute I am getting a 401 Unauthorized response, which is expected and default behaviour.

What I want to do next is instead of having that same call return a 401, I would like to return the status code to be 404.  (I don't want to get into great details of why 404.  Simply, I do not want to expose that the endpoint exists if a valid token is not included in request)

In previous .Net Framework WebAPI you could create your own attribute and override the HandleUnauthorizedRequest method and return the status code you want.

I have reviewed the documentation on policy-based authorization, but have not tried the sample or tried implementing it.  The policy handler looks more to do with handling (return success or fail) if a policy is not fulfilled.  I do not see anywhere where you can return a different status code on failure. So that only would make sense if I start checking against actual Policies.

Any insights?

Comment: This is a pointless endeavor. The only way anyone would know the endpoint exists, regardless, is if it's documented in some way. There's no way to "browse" an API. There has to be some listing of endpoints or documentation somewhere for clients to know that an endpoint exists. Assuming they know it exists, then returning a 404 just makes it look like your documentation is wrong. Worse, it now fails to actually provide useful info to the client, i.e. that they failed to provide authorization, preventing valid clients that merely made a mistake from knowing how to correct their mistake.

Comment: The 401 status exists for a reason: to let clients know they need to provide authorization.

Comment: The discussion of why 404 is not the real question.  Just looking to find out how to return a different status code.  Your points are definitely valid, however there are some internal policies and limitations I am also confined too.

Comment: What I'm saying is that there's not really a good way to do what you want, because it's no something that should be done in the first place. You might be able to hack something together, though I'm not sure what that would look like, but it's far easier and better to push back. Your job as a developer isn't to just blindly *do* whatever. If the manager-types and such knew how things worked, they wouldn't need you. And, just saying something isn't possible is always an option, even if the reality is that it's possible only with hacks.

Comment: Please mention your programming language for better answers

Comment: Quick solution is to remove authorize attribute and check inside the service whether provided token in the header `Authorization` is valid or not and return desired StatusCode. This is a quick workaround but it's not recommended whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

Returning 404 instead of 401 is bad practice(as mentioned in the comments by @Chris Pratt) and must be avoided. Consider these cases,

1. You're leaving the project to someone else and they can't figure why 404 is returned
2. A 404 is returned when you call the homepage/Index page. Poor ideology.
3. Later on in the project, you decide to allow post requests without authentication. So on and so forth.

Anyways, as part of the community, I'll give you the answer...

> Add this to your global.asax

```
void Application_EndRequest(object source, System.EventArgs args)
{
    if (Response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.RedirectToRoute("ErrorH", (RouteTable.Routes["ErrorH"] as Route).Defaults);
    }
}
```

> And in routeConfig, create a route for your errorHandler :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ErrorH",
    "Error/{action}/{errMsg}",
    new { controller = "CustomController", action = "Change401To404", errMsg = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

> And in your custom controller :

```
public class CustomController : Controller //or Base
{
    public ActionResult Change401To404(){
         //Do whatever you want
    }
}
```

PS: This is not the only way, there are many other ways to do it. But at least in this method, you can differentiate real 404 responses from 401 responses.